# Convergence of a series involving arctan

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to study the convergence of the series of functions
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n} \arctan\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2},$$
with $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to use the inequality $\arctan(x)\le\frac{\pi}{2},$ but I am not sure about that. Could someone please give me a hint? I'll post my (tenative) solution, but I need a hint for starting.

Thank you in advance!

${\bf EDIT:}$ (based on Tito Eliatron hint). I study the convergence of the power series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}.$$
By applying the square criterion, it is clear that the series converges when $x<3$ and diverges for $x>3$. Thus, for $x<3$, it is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n} \arctan\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}\sim\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}.$$

Moreover, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2},$$
which converges. Thus our starting series converges by comparison test. We only have to study the case $x=2$. In this case
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n} \arctan\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0$$
which converges.

Could someone please tell me if am I wrong with something? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the bounds might be incorrect. $n=1$ seems to give an infinite value to the summand.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
For those $x$ for wich $\sum \frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}$ is convergent, it follows that $\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}\to0$ so $\arctan \frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2} \sim \frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}$ and you can compare your series with $$\sum \frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2\ln n}.$$

Comment: Tito Eliatron, I edited the question using your hint. Could you please check if everything is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\left|\arctan x\right|\le |x|.$

Thus the series converges if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {\ln n} \cdot\frac{(x-2)^n}{n^2}$ converges, and a ratio test shows that that happens if $|x-2|<1.$ It also happens if $|x-2|=1,$ by comparison with $\sum_n 1/n^2.$

If $|x-2|>1,$ then the series diverges because the terms do not approach $0.$

Comment: Moreover, if $|\arctan(x)|\le|x|$, maybe the correct series to study involves $|x-2|^n$ instead of $(x-2)^n$, isn't it?

Comment: For $x-2<-1$, you have to study $\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n) n} (-\frac{\pi}{2})^n$ which diverges, isn' it? How to prove that?

Comment: @User1010 : Sorry --- I've now deleted my last paragraph. Maybe I'll replace it.

Comment: Michael Hardy, could you please answer my first question, too?